# WebView is not loading on iPhone

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am currently working on a news api for a react native app.  Everything seems to work fine on Android simulator, but my iOS device, iPhone 11 via the Expo app is just not loading the webview component. Stays in the isLoading state forever.  Any help on why this might be happening?

Comment: What is the url you try to load? Is it http or https?

Comment: I know is https, iPhone won't load http.  I tried with the expo app on my galaxy and do the same.  Willl try it in the iOS emulator on my mac and see if it works.  Thanks for your time.